# How to deserialize this Json in .net core?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

Hello I have this Json but I can't deserialize it:

```
    "Places":
"[{\"address\":\"Brussels, Belgium\",\"lat\":50.8503396,\"lng\":4.3517103},{\"address\":\"Amsterdam, Netherlands\",\"lat\":52.3675734,\"lng\":4.9041389}]"
```

I tried to add them in a collection but I get this error

```
"Error converting value \"[{\"address\":\"Brussels, Belgium\",\"lat\":50.8503396,\"lng\":4.3517103},{\"address\":\"Amsterdam, Netherlands\",\"lat\":52.3675734,\"lng\":4.9041389}]\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyMobiz.Models.Placess]'. Path 'Places', line 2, position 154."
```

Comment: You need to share proper json and the class to which you are trying to deserialize to along with the code which does the deserialization.

Comment: That's not legal JSON. Properties have to be inside objects, you're missing a `{...}` surrounding that JSON fragment. If that is the *entire* content of what you're trying to deserialize, then you should first wrap it in `{...}`, otherwise it is not legal and valid JSON.

Comment: I have a dynamic type where I store this json. I can access json.Places to print both of them but when I try json.Places[0] it gives me error

Comment: Secondly, what you have there is a single property that maps the string `"Places"` to another **string**, containing what seems to be more JSON. You need to deserialize this first into an object with a string property, which will then contain the embedded JSON, and then you need to deserialize this string into some other classes, essentially doing double deserialization.

Comment: Deserialize `json.Places` into another set of objects.

Comment: The JSON format is correct this is just a part of it . I forgot to put the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json shows the key and value both are strings. You will need to deserialize your value again to convert it to a list.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Places>>(obj[nameof(Places)].ToString());
```